# view pdf file in ionic 4 - page like terms and condition

Tags: ionic4, pdf-viewer, pdfview

I work in ionic 4 , and i want to make page contains 2 controls 
"PDF Viewer , checkbox" like Terms and condition

i cannot found any solution like this page , anyone have any idea or solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had used ng2-pdf-viewer plugin from https://github.com/vadimdez/ng2-pdf-viewer/

1- npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save

2- Add PdfViewerModule to your module's imports

```
   import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';



  @NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
```

3- create your page for exapmpe pdf-viewer-page
and in the module page add the import of your libarary
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HeaderModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    PdfViewerModule,
    PinchZoomModule,
  ],
```

4- in your html page

use thie tag

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf'"   style="display: block;" [zoom]="pdfZoom" [rotation]="rotation"
         [original-size]="false" [show-all] ="false" [page]="page"
         (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)" ></pdf-viewer>
```

I hope this help you